# Where is the part of the car that senses the i-key?

Tags: nissan, car, turn-signal, keyless-entry, maxima

My car is maxima 2014. Where is the part that receives the signals from the intelligent key?

Answer (score 5):

For the remote entry receiver see number 11 in the diagram below.

The interior key antenna is located under the center console number 13 and inputs to the body control module seen in number 1 of the diagram.

[image]

Comment: Nice diagram.  Where does it come from?

Comment: @MasonWheeler from a nissan service manual

Answer (score 5):

**Your BCM receives the signal**

Nissan uses what is called a BCM or body control module.

The BCM on your car controls the following

- Security (key fob synchronization, door locks)
- Turn signals
- Wipers
- Audio System
- Lights (internal/external)
- Anti-lock brakes

There are other attributes as well not on my list but to answer your question, it's the BCM.